# Как посчитать % заполнения формы на vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть data и в нем обьект s

```
data:()=> ({
    s:{
        a1: "",
        b2: "",
        c3: "",
        d4: ""
    },
    percent: 0
})
```

Есть 4 поля

```
<input v-model="s.a1" />
<input v-model="s.b2" />
<input v-model="s.c3" />
<input v-model="s.d4" />

<input :value="`${percent}%`" readonly />
```

Нужно что бы в функции вычислялся % заполнения формы, не понимаю по какой формуле это надо сделать.

Мне нужно вывести в 5ом поле какой % заполнен и сколько осталось

```
calculatePercent(){

}
```

Comment: Давайте рассмотрим задачу с точки зрения математики. 

У нас 4 инпута, заполнение каждого инпута повысит уровень заполнености на 25% (100 / 4 = 25), 
из этого исходит, что достаточно узнать количество заполненых полей, и умножить это число на 25.

Comment: @АндрейАлександру спасибо, уловил мысль))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
computed: {
  percent() {
    return Object.keys(this.s).filter(v => this.s[v]).length * 25
  }
},
```

```html
<span>{{percent}}</span>
```